# How to output all the processor at same time in Nifi so that I can get same UUID() value for an Attribute

Tags: compare, uuid, apache-nifi, processor

I am generating a Json Array from two separate MergeContent Processor, both have a common Attribute call pointId(i.e UUID()) but I am not able to get the same PointId from MergeContent. 
I am passing the same PointId to both MergeContent, but I am not able to get common pointId from both merge processor.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NIFI how to change uuid to file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965798/nifi-how-to-change-uuid-to-file-name)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set Correlation Attribute Name to `pointId` in MergeContent? If so, how many bins are you using and how many unique IDs could be in the system at once?