# NIFI how to change uuid to file name

Tags: marklogic, apache-nifi

I have some documents in XML format load into Marklogic.
The PutMarkLogic URI attribute Name property default "uuid".  How can I change it to file name.

Input Directory:

```
/input/ac01010.xml
/input/ac02010.xml
 ....
```

I have two processors below

GetFile ->PutMarkLogic

Want Marklogic display documents:

```
ac01010.xml
ac02010.xml
```

Thanks Andy and Ben.  I have updated UpdateAttribute and PutMarkLogic properties in Nifi. it works.

[image: Nifi PutMarkLogic]

UpdateAttribute:added ${filename}
[image: UpdateAttribute]

PutMarkLogic Property:
[image: PutMarkLogic Property]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `UpdateAttribute` processor to populate the *filename* attribute with the value of the *uuid* attribute by adding a dynamic property with name *filename* and value `${uuid}`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the uuid of a FlowFile.. You can however, change the uuid **attribute** using `UpdateAttribute` as @Andy mentioned.

Seems from the [code](https://github.com/marklogic/nifi/blob/ml-release/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-marklogic-bundle/nifi-marklogic-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/marklogic/processor/PutMarkLogic.java) that it uses the `uuid` attribute. So you can just set property name of `UpdateAttribute` as `uuid` and value as `${filename}` or just the filename you wish to put and it should do the job.

Comment: I added property name filename and value ${uuid} in UpdateAttribute.  GetFile->UpdateAttribute->PutMarklogic.  The result after insert in Marklogic database displays uuid 30d29b5d-d86b-42e9-b801-8179248a5c4c But not file name. How to display in xml file name.